# Execute a groovy script on click in XWiki

Tags: groovy, xwiki

I can't figure out how to run a simple groovy script in xwiki when clicking on a link/button? I don't want the script to be started when the xwiki page is loaded. 
The script itself is working fine but how can I connect the script with an push event on the button?

Is there any easy way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy is to use the HTML macro, use an HTML format and call the same page but passing a parameter to recognize that the button has been clicked. If you want a link, simply call the same page using for example `[[label>>||queryString="confirm=1"]]` and then do an `#if` in Velocity.

Here's an example:
https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/FAQ/How%20can%20I%20create%20a%20new%20page%20based%20on%20a%20form

Comment: Thanks, that`s what I was looking for. Works perfectly!